# Append pandas dataframe with dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have the following dictionary and I want to add these in to a pandas dataframe:

```
crimes1 = {'SOUTHERN': 28445,
 'NORTHERN': 20100,
 'MISSION': 19503}
```

I create the blank dataframe with the column names I want:

```
column_names = ['Neighborhood', 'Count']
crimes2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

Next I want to append the dataframe with my dictionary containing the keys and values above using a for loop:

```
for i, x in crimes1:
    crimes2 = crimes2.append({'Neighborhood': i}, {'Count': x}, ignore_index=True)
```

The error I get is `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I can populate only one column when I do it separately but can't seem to get both in to the one dataframe. Any ideas on how to get this to work using the for loop above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `ValueError` because you are not calling `crimes1.items()` which is require to iterate over the key, value pairs of dictionary. Simply, Use:

```
for i, x in crimes1.items():
    crimes2 = crimes2.append({'Neighborhood': i, 'Count': x}, ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
# print(crimes2)
  Neighborhood  Count
0     SOUTHERN  28445
1     NORTHERN  20100
2      MISSION  19503
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function

```
crimes2 = pd.DataFrame(map(list, crimes1.items()))

crimes2.columns = ['Neighborhood', 'Count']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
crimes2 = pd.DataFrame(crimes1.items(), columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'])
  Neighborhood  Count
0     SOUTHERN  28445
1     NORTHERN  20100
2      MISSION  19503
```